# TypeError trying to upload to mongoDB

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, typeerror

So I am trying to upload the username, email and password to mongoDB with this script using a button on click event it fires however I get and error stating that there is a reference error with user.

```
var User = require('../models/user'); 
    function get() {
            var user = new User({
                username: "sd",
                email: "sss@gmail.com",
                test: "tes123"
            });
            user.save().then(function(data) {
                console.log("user has been inserted");
                console.log(data);
                update(); // Calling immediately to quick test only....
            }).catch(function(e) {
                console.log("Failed", e)
            });
        }
```

and I call the function get with this

```
  <input type="text" id="usernameRegister" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter name...">
  <input type="text" id="passwordRegister" class="form-control" placeholder="EnterPassword...">
  <button onclick="get(usernameRegister.value,passwordRegister.value)">Register</button>
```

and then in models/user

```
var User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema); module.exports = User;
```

and this is the error I am receiving

```
TypeError: User is not a constructor[Learn More] router.js:44:14
get
http://localhost:3000/routes/router.js:44:14
onclick
http://localhost:3000/:1:1
```

also it works if I do not call it with a button so I do not know why it is doing this any help would be greatly appreciated thank you.

Comment: So where is the code showing where `User` is coming from? That's the error, so it's important to post details about that within your question. Please show the line where you import from another file ( if that's what you're doing ) and similarly where that is the case then that actual code which is defining this model.

Comment: var User = require('../models/user');            and then in models/user var User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
module.exports = User;         My bad even still though is this the case when it works when I just leave it outside the get() function and it will run on load?

Comment: There's an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53113565/edit) link on your question. Please "edit your question" with additional details as nobody has the time to trawl through comments for relevant information. Make your question clear and easy to find information and you get answers

Comment: I added it to it